# Schema applied on Magento Doesnt appear in richsnippet tool

Tags: magento, schema, rich-snippets, structured-data, google-rich-snippets

I have added richsnippet code as per this online tutor http://www.creare.co.uk/magento-product-schema on my website. But I am not able to see schema code to appear here is an example of how it shows http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbangbang.kz%2Fguitars%2Fukulele%2Fbajtursynova-159.html

Can I know if there is any issues.

If there is any issues can you give me an idea regards to which files I have to edit and what code to be added.

Answer (score 0):

url address is case sensitive,

```
type: http://schema.org/product
type: http://schema.org/offer
type: http://schema.org/aggregaterating
```

that url is wrong, you type the wrong url for markup the correct url is :

```
type: http://schema.org/Product
type: http://schema.org/Offer
type: http://schema.org/AggregateRating
```

did you see the difference ?

Open your template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
div class=”product-essential”: Insert the itemtype
<div class="product-essential" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

div class=”product-name”: Insert the product name
<div class="product-name" itemprop="name">

div class=”std”: Insert the product description
<div class="std" itemprop="description">
```

Open your template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

```
img id=”image: Insert the product image type
<img id="image" itemprop="image"
```

Open your template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml

If you don’t have a div wrapping this entire code block paste the below, if you do just alter it.

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

class=”price-block”: Insert the product price
<div class="price-block" itemprop="price">

Comment out “echo $this->__(‘Availability:’)” and insert this before it
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
```

Open your template/review/helper/summary.phtml

```
 <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope
 itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"> <?php if
 ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>  <meta itemprop="ratingValue"
 content="<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary(); ?>"/> <meta
 itemprop="reviewCount" content="<?php echo $this->getReviewsCount();
 ?>" /> <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="100"/> <meta
 itemprop="worstRating" content="0"/> …. </span>
```

also i suggest you register google Plus, because there is no authorship and publisher markup for your website

if you need simple method, used google webmaster tools and edit product markup there